# Can't exec “locale”: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, steam, aptitude, locale

I am new to linux. I tried today to install steam on my Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit through the .deb from the steam website. On launch, steam gave me the following error: "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6"
I tried to follow a few tutorials online, I will update when I find them again, and installed a some different 32-bit libraries. Now I get this error each time I try to use apt-get or even open the software center.

```
installArchives() failed: Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
Error in function:
```

What should I do ?

Update:

This is the installation I followed, which produced a dangerous warning at one point:

```
sudo apt-get install libc-bin:i386
```

Comment: the $PATH is not set right. Try running this as root: "export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" and then apt-get install steam

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/environment` ?

Comment: might be related to those bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/33475

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/16739

Comment: @Kenn PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin`

Answer (score 3):

I read an article and followed the instruction, My problem is fixed so you must read it -   http://itsfoss.com/fix-exec-locale-file-directory/